# Edit Script button in SSDT_BI2012 doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, vsta

I'm a new to SSIS development and I'm using a 64-bit computer on Windows 7. I wanted to change a script task, but when clicking on the 'Edit Script' button nothing happens.
Here is the ScriptLanguage searched:

[image]

I tried a new installation VS2012 and SSDT_BI2012, as suggested on different forums, but that doesn't fixed my issue.

If anyone had the same issue can you guide me to the resolution?

If you need additional information please let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here is what I did to fix this issue:

- Go to the control panel and locate the instance of Visual Studio Tools for Applications (VSTA). 
  In your case you should look for something like "**Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2012**"
- Right click on the VSTA component and select "**Change**"
- In the next popup click "**Repair**"

In my case the problem was with Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2017:

[image]

Once I repaired this VSTA installation everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried to repair the Visual Studio with the installation, but it didn't work.

**After, the solution that worked for me:**

Install the SSDT in a new instance of Visual studio.